# Prismjs highlight file

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, plugins, prismjs

I'm trying to highlight C++ file with Prismjs https://prismjs.com/index.html file highlight plugin https://prismjs.com/plugins/file-highlight/. So I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
    <link href="themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="prism.js"></script>
    <pre data-src="main.cpp"></pre>
    <pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

But its not working. The piece of CSS appear there but the `main.cpp` (which is in the same folder as `index.html` and `prism.js`) don't show up. I got:

[image]

Any suggestion on were should I look?

I'm not used to html/css/js.

Answer (score 2):

You did not select the 'file highlight' plugin when you downloaded prism. Just had the same problem. Downloaded it again with it selected and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Norman Potts you need to add the file highlight plugin.

I used:
https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript+c+cpp+json&plugins=line-highlight+line-numbers+file-highlight+keep-markup+unescaped-markup

also you only need this

```
<pre data-src="main.cpp"></pre>
```

not this

```
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```