# Highlight haskell file content using Prism.js

Tags: javascript, html, prism.js

I'm trying to highlight the Haskell code piece using Prism.js

Below is the sample HTML code which properly highlighting code

```
<pre><code id="codecontent1" class="language-haskell">import Data.List
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

area h w xs = 2 * h * w + count xs + count (rotate xs)
  where rotate = reverse . transpose
        count = sum . map diff
        diff ys = sum $ zipWith ((abs .) . (-)) (0 : ys) (ys ++ [0])


solve :: [Int] -> Int
solve (h:w:xs) = area h w (chunksOf w $ xs)

main = interact $ show . solve . map read . words
</code></pre>
```

Output:
[image]

But when try to load the code dynamically (from github repo) it is not properly getting highlighted.
HTML Code:

```
<pre><code id="codecontent" class="language-haskell">loading..</code></pre>
```

JS code to load content:

```
function load_code (probname) {
    var url = 'https://rawgit.com/tuxian-root/hackerrank-solutions/master/' + probname + '.hs';
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", url, true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
            if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
                allText = txtFile.responseText;
                //lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
                document.getElementById("codecontent").textContent = txtFile.responseText;
                document.getElementById("codecontent").setAttribute("class", "language-haskell language-markup");
            }
        }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);
    //document.getElementById("codecontent").setAttribute("class", "language-haskell");
}
```

calling part:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;" onload="load_code('algorithms/implementation/3d-surface-area.hs')"></body>
```

output:
[image]

I've also tried below, but didn't worked.

```
<pre data-src="https://github.com/tuxian-root/hackerrank-solutions/blob/master/algorithms/implementation/3d-surface-area.hs"></pre>
```

Can someone please help me find what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue that while downloading prism.css/prism.js i missed file highlight option

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246906/2173020